# How to put multiple Canvasses into a single HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have three javascript files (the beginning of each is shown below). Each subsequent declaration is in a separate file - so variable names overlapping should not be an issue.

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let labels = ['Banking', 'Finances', 'Shopping', 'Recreation', 'Healthcare', 'Transportation', 'Food and Drink'];
let colorHex = ['#FB3640', '#86A9C5', '#286CA1', '#77FAC', '#1C203D', '#798E9C', '#2A303D'];

let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
      backgroundColor: colorHex,
      borderWidth: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    }],
    labels: labels,
  
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    
    
    plugins: {
      
      datalabels: {
        color: '#fff',
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'start',
        offset: 10,
        borderWidth: 0,
        // borderColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 0,
        
        font: {
          size: '10',
          color: '#fff'
        },
        formatter: (value) => {
          return value + ' %';
        }
      }
    }
  }
})


let ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
let labels2 = ['Banking', 'Finances', 'Shopping', 'Recreation', 'Healthcare', 'Transportation', 'Food and Drink'];
let colorHex2 = ['#FB3640', '#86A9C5', '#286CA1', '#77FAC', '#1C203D', '#798E9C', '#2A303D'];
let myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
  
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
      backgroundColor: colorHex,
      borderWidth: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    }],
    labels: labels,
  
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    
    
    plugins: {
      
      datalabels: {
        color: '#fff',
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'start',
        offset: 10,
        borderWidth: 0,
        // borderColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 0,
        
        font: {
          size: '10',
          color: '#fff'
        },
        formatter: (value) => {
          return value + ' %';
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

let ctx3 = document.getElementById('myChart3').getContext('2d');
let labels3 = ['Banking', 'Finances', 'Shopping', 'Recreation', 'Healthcare', 'Transportation', 'Food and Drink'];
let colorHex3 = ['#FB3640', '#86A9C5', '#286CA1', '#77FAC', '#1C203D', '#798E9C', '#2A303D'];
let myChart3 = new Chart(ctx3, {
  
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
      backgroundColor: colorHex,
      borderWidth: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    }],
    labels: labels,
  
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    
    
    plugins: {
      
      datalabels: {
        color: '#fff',
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'start',
        offset: 10,
        borderWidth: 0,
        // borderColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 0,
        
        font: {
          size: '10',
          color: '#fff'
        },
        formatter: (value) => {
          return value + ' %';
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

However, when I embed them into my html file (shown below) only the first one shows up.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Viewer | Analysis</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/analysis.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
  <script src="./js/script.js"></script>

  
  <script src="Chart3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <header class = "Header">Hi</header> -->
  
  <div class = "sidenav">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <script src="Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div class="Top-Box">
     
    <div class = "Translucent-Box">
       <h1 class = "Box-Header">Categorical Spending Left</h1>
       <canvas id= "myChart" height="250" width="250"></canvas>
     </div>
   
     <div class = "Translucent-Box">
       <h1 class = "Box-Header">Categorical Spending Center</h1>
       <canvas id = "myChart2" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
       <canvas class ="myChart2" width="640" height="480" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1"></canvas> 
     </div>  
   
     <div class = "Translucent-Box">
       <h1 class = "Box-Header">Categorical Spending Left</h1>
       <canvas id = "myChart3" height="250" width="250"></canvas>
     </div> 
   
   </div>
  


</body>

</html>
```

I've been stuck on this for a few hours so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: Whats even more bizarre is that I made a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/EDP1000/sc38nr2p/2/ - and it works perfectly. HOwever, when I run my code in VSCode it does not.

Comment: I think the reason is that you defined the duplicate variable name through `let`, such as `labels` or `colorHex `.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use 'labels' and 'colorHex' which may overlapping

Comment: They are in seperate files

Comment: What do you see in console? Any errors?

Comment: No errors - it simply doesn't show any of the graphs that I want

Comment: Where is you `<canvas>` of `id="myChart3"` ?

Comment: But I don't see how you draw anything. Also myChart2 exists twice

Comment: I made an example: https://codepen.io/ms314006/pen/RwGMqGm.

Comment: I edited the post to show my full code to avoid any confusion - thanks for the quick responses

Comment: What is in the content of the CSS class `.Translucent-Box`? Any chance they are overlapping with each other? Also, suggested to use lowercase for every file name and CSS class, btw. Please make a JSFiddle if possible.

Comment: The idea that you can use the same variable names in global scope because they are in differerent script files is simply wrong. The fact that you are not getting errors on the console means either some or all of the files are not being included (check to the network tab for confirmation) or the description of the problem is lacking details. The codepen does what it is coded to do without errors.

Comment: I made a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/EDP1000/sc38nr2p/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think using `let` to declare your variables instead of a global declaration is the issue. If all other elements like font and color I'd have that info only needed one time, the information that varies, would just need file reference ID part and then heading but would eliminate the multiple variables being repeated within a local declaration rather than a global declaration

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it's a combo of a bunch of things.

You've got pretty messy syntax and a lot of `<div id = 'thing spaces'...` and stuff. I also think there's some conflicting absolute positioning.

Since these graphs are repeating in your example, I wrapped that code in a function to clearly scope the variables.

```
function createChart(whateverCanvasId) {
  let ctx = document.getElementById(whateverCanvasId).getContext('2d');
  // do whatever stuff...
}

createChart('myChart');
createChart('myChart2');
createChart('myChart3');
```

and put it in a very simplified CodePen. (we don't need to know about all the other details)

https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/2f6bd5956c9f8bd928f957a4f09d8844?editors=0010

I'm not totally sure what the problem is... but keep cleaning it up and stripping it down until you get to the bottom of it.